# In Excel, I want to make the text of a cell disappear if the adjacent cell is blank

Tags: excel-formula

In Excel, I want to make the text of a cell disappear if the adjacent cell is blank. Or the reverse: when text is entered into a cell, a specified number appears in the adjacent cell.
Ex. When any text is entered into A4, the number 43210 appears in cell B4.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Formula in cell B4

```
=IF(ISBLANK(A4),"",43210)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also use conditional formatting, stablishing a rule that sets text colour to white using the formula

=$A4<>""

on cell B4